# How to forward SOAP request through ACTIVE MQ JMS to my Services with the support of MULE

Tags: soap, jms, activemq-classic, mule, esb

We have produced JAX-WS web-services with the help of Java API and published. Now we would like to queuing  the requests, which are coming for the services with the help of JMS. We chosen the ACTIVE MQ JMS Server with the combination of MULE ESB.

We have tried the proxying of webservices with the help of two Http Endpoints. It is working fine. So When i trying to test it by sending request from SOAP UI to Http inbound end point, it is forwarding request to my services and get back the response to SOAP UI.

But when we are trying to put the JMS endpoint in between these Http end points, the request is forwarded to my services, but not the message (SOAP).

Please help me to resolve the issue or suggest me the alternative way for Queuing.

Following image shows flow in MULE.

.
      [image]

Following is the flow :

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ1" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ"/>
<flow name="finalFlow1" doc:name="finalFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8888" contentType="text/xml" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queue="servicesQueue" connector-ref="Active_MQ1" doc:name="JMS"/>
    <http:outbound-endpoint mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" path="MyServices" host="localhost" port="5050" />
</flow>
```

Actually MyServices is produced at `http://localhost:5050/MyServices`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably due to that you are expecting a string payload in your JMS queue and the http:inbound-endpoint produces a stream payload.

Try putting `<object-to-string-transformer/>` before the jms:outbound-endpoint.

Comment: It looks correct otherwise. You just need to add the transformer.

Comment: How can i find, if there is any problem in Active MQ?

Comment: You can debug your application by replacing your JMS application with a Mule JMS endpoint that prints and returns the payload: <flow name="jmsFlow" doc:name="jmsFlow">
   <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="servicesQueue" connector-ref="Active_MQ1" doc:name="JMS"/>
   <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>    
</flow>

Comment: Thank you @Anton Kupias, It is working by putting <object-to-string-transformer/>.

Comment: Hi @Anton Kupias,
It is working. But in ACTIVE MQ web console it is showing the count of messages under "Number Of Pending Messages". But myservices got the request with soap message and and it responds to client.

Comment: Could be a problem with your ActimeMQ subscriber or ActimeMQ version. Some older ActimeMQ versions have bugs related to the pending lists.

Comment: Now we are using Apache-ActiveMq- 5.9.0

Comment: & we have used JMS exchange pattern is one-way. 
Is it a problem?
If we use request-response. we are getting some problems

Comment: One-way pattern sounds like it is an issue with your JMS subscriber not sending an ack for the received message, and I think that is no more a Mule issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46914/discussion-between-sampoornesh-babu-and-anton-kupias)